# ActiveRecord:Record not found error in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line of code in my model:

```
pay_period = TimesheetPayPeriod.find(:first, :conditions => ["start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", date.to_date, date.to_date])
```

and I am getting this error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all TimesheetPayPeriods with 'id': (first, {:conditions=>["start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", Fri, 03 Mar 2017, Fri, 03 Mar 2017]}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)):

What does this error mean and how can I correct it?

Comment: This is very old syntax, did you find this online somewhere or inherit an ancient project?

Comment: inheriting an ancient project!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to use the new syntax

```
pay_period = 
  TimesheetPayPeriod.where("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", date.to_date, date.to_date).first
```

Answer (score 2):

`.find()` is expecting the value of the id. so it would be `.find(34)` for example.

Could you try using `.where()`

```
pay_period = TimesheetPayPeriod.where("start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", date.to_date, date.to_date)
```

You might wanna check the docs that the args are valid, but think this should work.